# How to search by array elements in elasticsearch?

Tags: arrays, indexing, elasticsearch

I have a document indexed in elasticsearch:

```
{
    "content":"Some content with @someone mention",
    "mentions":["someone"],
    "userId":"4dff31eaf8815f4df04e2d62"
}
```

I try to find it with a query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": { "term":{"userId":"4dff31eaf8815f4df04e2d62"} },
            "query": {
                term: {"mentions":"someone"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and receive no results.

In the same time query for content works fine:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": { "term":{"userId":"4dff31eaf8815f4df04e2d62"} },
            "query": {
                "term": {"content":"some"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is some special syntax required for search through arrays? I found several topics [[1](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Search-inside-field-with-nested-array-td2293927.html), [2](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Query-Syntax-for-arrays-and-nested-objects-td212582.html)] about arrays in elasticsearch, but there is no direct answer.

**UPD** Get Mapping call returns the next result:

```
{
    "records": {
        "all":{
            "properties":{
                "content":{"type":"string"},
                "userId":{"type":"string"},
                "mentions":{"type":"string"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD2** I found the source of problem. I accidentally introduced an error into my question. The username I actually had in DB was in form "some_one" (underscore is significant). So standard index split it into 2 words and query for "some_one" of cause failing.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with default settings/mapping. What is the mapping for this field?

Comment: @imotov AFAIK there is no any non-default mapping. I updated question with the "get mapping" api call result.

Comment: That's how it looks like when I run it on my machine: https://gist.github.com/1048874 Do you get different results? I also noticed that term in the first query is not surrounded by quotes. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @imotov i did a mistake, when posted this question (see upd2). But thank you, without your example I would newer done the correct experiment.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct usage, as your update mentions.

If you import a document with a "mentions" array, searching on a matching array item, referring to it as "mentions", will retrieve the document. I had the same issue and verified it myself just now.