# Elasticsearch sort by single nested document key in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents which look like this (here are two examples):

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "title": "the title",
    "body": "the body",
    "examples": [
        {
            "evidence_source": "friend",
            "source_score": 15
        },
        {
            "evidence_source": "parent",
            "source_score": 12
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "id": 6346,
    "title": "new title",
    "body": "lots of content",
    "examples": [
        {
            "evidence_source": "friend",
            "source_score": 10
        },
        {
            "evidence_source": "parent",
            "source_score": 27
        },
        {
            "evidence_source": "child",
            "source_score": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

The format of the sub-documents in the `examples` array will always have an `evidence_source` and a `source_score` but there will be a variable amount of these sub-documents, each with different `evidence_source` values.

I am wondering if it is possible to sort documents with this format based on one of the `source_score` values matched to a specific `evidence_source` value. I'd really like to be able to do this:

- Sort documents by `source_score` descending where the related `evidence_source` is `friend`. The resulting ordering of the document `id`s would be 1234,6346.
- Sort documents by `source_score` descending where the related `evidence_source` is `parent`. The resulting ordering of the document `id`s would be 6346,1234.

The closest results that I'm come up with for doing something like this are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465852/how-to-search-by-array-elements-in-elasticsearch) and [2](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Query-Syntax-for-arrays-and-nested-objects-td212582.html) but I don't believe that they get at exactly what I want to do.

Any ideas about how I might go about this? I've contemplated some ideas based on indexing these `examples` sub-documents separately, but I'm fairly new to elasticsearch and so am looking for some advice on a how to achieve my goal in the most straightforward manner (which may be a pipe-dream...)

**Update**: A post on the [elasticsearch mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/elasticsearch/ldRIB0YYbB4/discussion) seems to indicate that this is NOT possible, but I'm wondering if someone else here has any different ideas!

Comment: Are subdocuments mapped as nested documents or as objects? How many records do you expect to have in your index?

Comment: Right now, I'm actually not mapping them specially at all, but I'm willing to try to experiment with different mappings to arrive at the functionality I'm looking for. I'm expecting on the order of 100 million records total stored.

Comment: How many different types of evidence_source are you planning to have?

Comment: Somewhere between 5 and 10, and not every document will have exactly the same evidence_source blocks.

Comment: I am just thinking it might be easier, if you modified schema by moving evidence type into the field name: "examples": { "friend" : {"source_score": 10}, "parent": {"source_score": 27},  "child": {"source_score": 4}}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Support for sorting based on fields inside of nested documents was added to elasticsearch in 0.90:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2662

> The sorting by nested field support has the following parameters on
>   top of the already existing sort options:
>
> - `nested_path` - Defines the on what nested object to sort. The actual
>     sort field must be a direct field inside this nested object. The
>     default is to use the most immediate inherited nested object from the
>     sort field.
> - `nested_filter` - A filter the inner objects inside the
>     nested path should match with in order for its field values to be
>     taken into account by sorting. Common case is to repeat the query /
>     filter inside the nested filter or query. By default no `nested_filter`
>     is active.

Given your example data, the following query should give you what you're after:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "examples.source_score": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "examples",
        "nested_filter": {
          "term": {
            "examples.evidence_source": "friend"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use above query when there is parent child relationship ?

Comment: @PrasadBhosale It's not possible because it's for Nested Object only. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html

Comment: Is it possible to use a bool query inside the nested filter?

Comment: @SvenMäurer - it should be possible. are you having any issue with `bool` query ?